# BackPack: How to have Users that can't access to admin?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to use BackPack for Laravel to manage the contents/users of my WebApp.

My WebApp have users, and these users can access to another private area (outside BackPack)

I want that the users don't have access to the BackPack Admin Panel when the're logged in.
Also, even they can't never access to /admin

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the default in Backpack v5. Make sure you [use separate login forms and middleware](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/base-how-to#use-separate-login-register-forms-for-users-and-admins) for your users and admin:

- the `backpack` middleware for the admins
- Laravel's `auth` middleware for your users

Alternatively, you can use the same login forms and middleware, and use the `App\Http\CheckIfAdmin.php` middleware to define what makes an admin and admin.